# Create Vanilla C++ project in QtCreator from existing .cpp and .h files

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I want to start using QtCreator for C++ coding...

However, I need to understand how I can create a new project - just a straight C++ project (not Qt) - from a bunch of existing .cpp and header files. How do I import these into a new C++ project...? How do I get it built...? How do I get QtCreator to build all the neccessary make files etc...?

Been googling this for ages without finding a straight answer.

many thanks

Answer (score 2):

C++ uses a compiler (like `gcc`) for compiling and a linker (like `ld` aka `gcc`) for linking. You will be typically compiling multiple C++ files all of which will need to be linked together.

The script that will do all of this for you is normally a `Makefile` that is executed using the `make` program.

Qt has a tool called [`qmake`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-manual.html) that can do most of the leg-work for you. Normally you go to the directory with your source, run `qmake -project` to generate a Qt project then run `qmake` to generate a standard Makefile. finally you call make to build your source.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got there in the end.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.0/index.html) of Qt Creator is available online so it is a bit surprising that Google could not help you find it.

Creating Projects: https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.0/creator-project-creating.html

Building and Running: https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.0/creator-building-running.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually it seems not quite as straightforward as you may imagine. Apparently a good amount of the documentation relating to using QtCreator as a straight C++ IDE has been removed. It can still be done but you have to run qmake -project from the command line. Thanks anyway.